# apex add list to list

Tags: apex, list, array

I have this code:

```
String cantidad;
String total;

List<List<String>> pList = new List<List<String>>();
List<String> lstStr = new List<String>();
List<QuoteLineItem> acList = [SELECT Quantity, total__c FROM QuoteLineItem 
WHERE QuoteId = '0Q01D00'];

    for(QuoteLineItem ac : acList)
    {
        cantidad = string.valueOf(ac.Quantity); 
        total = string.valueOf(ac.total__c);
        lstStr.add(cantidad);
        lstStr.add(total);
    }
    pList.add(lstStr);
System.debug(pList);
```

the output is:

```
((2.00, 10.00, 1.00, 10.00, 1.00, 10.00, 2.00, 44.00))
```

Im trying to separate each 2 values. it should show this:

```
((2.00, 10.00), (1.00, 10.00), (1.00, 10.00), (2.00, 44.00))
```

So i can access them like pList[0], pList[1], pList[2], pList[3]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the instance of the list you are working with is constantly being built with new values. To solve your issue, you could use the following

```
List<List<String>> pList = new List<List<String>>();

for (QuoteLineItem ac : [SELECT Quantity, total__c FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId = '0Q01D00']) {
    pList.add(new List<String>{String.valueOf(ac.Quantity), String.valueOf(ac.total__c)});
}
System.debug(pList[0]);
System.debug(pList[1]);
```

Note, the for loop has become a [soql for loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm). You may also consider the use of a [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) to related collection data but note, the `get()` method does not support indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below to solve your issue. Array can be assigned to list.

```
String cantidad;
String total;

List<List<String>> pList = new List<List<String>>();
List<String> lstStr = null;
List<QuoteLineItem> acList = [SELECT Quantity, total__c FROM QuoteLineItem 
WHERE QuoteId = '0Q01D00'];

    for(QuoteLineItem ac : acList)
    {
        lstStr = new string[2];
        cantidad = string.valueOf(ac.Quantity); 
        total = string.valueOf(ac.total__c);
        lstStr[0]=cantidad;
        lstStr[1]=total;
        pList.add(lstStr);
    }
   System.debug(pList[0]);
```